# Can Lyx syntax files override document class defaults?

Tags: lyx, document-classes, tools, conversion

I'm editing a client's Latex file in Lyx, where the client has used a document class not supported by Lyx.

In these cases, I use `tex2lyx` with either `-c article` or `-c report` to  ensure Lyx can import the file, and look at the difference (using `wdiff`) between the provided Latex file and that which Lyx exports to assemble a list of misunderstood syntax, which I can create a syntax file from to pass to `tex2lyx` using the `-s $SYNTAXFILE` option.

All well and good, but if the document classes conflict in their syntax (e.g., passing optional arguments to such commands as `\author` or environments such as `{enumerate}`) then Lyx ignores what the syntax file says and so misparses the imported Latex file.

I have a workaround for this case, namely putting the definition `\let\lyxtexblock=\relax` in the Latex preamble and a line `\lyxtexblock{}` in the syntax file, and surrounding any misunderstood Latex with it.  But I wonder if there is a more principled solution, something less time-consuming than hacking up a new layout file.

I'm using Lyx 1.6.8, but I'm interested to hear of solutions for Lyx 2.

#### Resource

- [Converting *.tex to *.lyx](http://wiki.lyx.org/LaTeX/LatexToLyx) (lyx.org wiki)

### Motivation

While it is possible to edit someone else's Latex manuscript by directly editing the source file, and use `wdiff/texdiff/latexdiff` to document the changes made, this tends to be a relatively inefficient way of working when there are many edits (say 1 000 edits on a 9 000 word manuscript).  The change tracking features of Word, Open Office Writer and Lyx all offer the following features, among others, which I call the *change-tracking minimum*:

1. Comments associated with changed text, ideally over arbitrary extents of text or particular edits;
2. A UI that allows changes to be worked through one at a time, and accepted, rejected, or the text modified;
3. A UI that allows all changes in some selected portion of text to either accepted or rejected, and likewise all comments in a slected area be deleted;

Point one is possible with `wdiff/texdiff/latexdiff`.  Neither points 2 or 3 are, with any software I have seen.  Anything less than all three points will cause a big increase in the time it takes for a client of mine to work through the kind of edits I produce.  I believe the lack of good editing tools for Latex, such as the above, is the principal reason why many publishers do not want to work within Latex.

Comment: Wouldn't the best solution be to use TeXworks or some other editor?

Comment: @Seamus: Solution to what?  I need change tracking.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be that you're using LyX. The solution is to stop doing so.

Comment: @Seamus: I've added a postscript explaining why I find this worthwhile.

Comment: Which documentclass is it? It is not too complicated to write an own layout file for LyX, which makes live much more easier than using tex2lyx

Comment: @Herbert: This isn't one document, it is something I have tried and considered trying with many client texts with many bespoke journal document classes.  I generally substitute article or book class if it is something Lyx doesn't recognise.  The workload of authoring format files is too time-consuming to be an option for most assignments; likewise asking clients to install my homespun format files is something I would rather not do.  I much prefer to ask them to edit the Latex with Word, to be honest; it has been the least problematic way of handling Latex sources in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the "more principled" solution you have asked for, but another workaround that has been working pretty well for me when editing foreign articles:

1. I technically **do** create an own layout file, but **do not** put any effort into it. I just take a copy of `article.layout` (or one of its descendants) and edit the class file inside the copy and that's all.
2. I do live with ERT boxes for everything that is nonstandard

The issue with ERT boxes is that changes inside them are not tracked by LyX's change tracking system. However, 
in my experience (with classes for scientific articles) most, if not all, incompatibilities to the standard classes affect only the front matter, that is, macros such as `\title`, `\author`, `\thanks` and so on. So I usually end up with one big ERT box at the beginning that contains a verbatim copy of the front matter from the LaTeX source and  use `tex2lyx` to convert only the body of the article. As edits to the front matter are relatively rare, this is an acceptable low-effort workaround.

Comment: I'd much rather edit the highlighted source in Word than do this.  There are journals that use custom macros for such things as scientific units, natbib-like citations, and figure text, all of which are sensitive texts often in need of change tracking.  But its worth documenting this, so I'll upvote.