# Space between Hebrew letters larger with MacTeX than with MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, spacing, miktex, mactex, hebrew

I'm writing LaTeX using LyX on Macintosh, and in Hebrew. My problem is that when exporting the document I get bigger spaces between my Hebrew letters than if compiling the same file on a Windows machine, with MiKTeX. The problem is not specific to LyX; even when I export a LaTeX file I see the same difference in letter spacing. Where can I change the spacing between the letters?

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
‎זוהי דוגמה לכך שהרווחים כאן בעברית גדולים מדי. זוהי דוגמה לכך שהרווחים כאן בעברית גדולים מדי. זוהי דוגמה לכך שהרווחים כאן בעברית גדולים מדי. זוהי דוגמה לכך שהרווחים כאן בעברית גדולים מדי.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! ... Can you reproduce the problem with just a LaTeX file? It would help if you could provide a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5640)Also, which TeX distribution are you using on each of the machines?

Comment: what do you mean by just a LaTex file? I have MacTex 2010 on the macintosh, and on the windows machine there's MikTex 2.9. I could provide 2 pdf files and you could see the differences - is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant [export to LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/converting-lyx-to-latex) instead of all the way to a PDF. LyX should have this capability.

Comment: i saw that i can export to LaTex file. but what should i do with the file? i don't see even how to upload it here.

Comment: Try to compile the file with both MaCTeX and MiKTeX. Assuming you get the same results, we've begun to narrow down the problem. Then try to minimize the file as much as possible (see the MWE link above). Finally, edit your question and add its contents as a source block.

Comment: yes. I do get the same results. I put a tex document in my post as you requested.

Comment: Ok, now try stripping out as much of it as you can while still seeing the bug. When you've done so, please also post screenshots of a relevant part of the output. Finally, you can try replacing the gibberish with actual Hebrew, saving your file in UTF-8 charset encoding, and changing `\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Comment: sorry, but i tried to erase some of the lines in the file, but nothing helped, and then - after erasing too much i guess - i got errors and wasn't able to compile the file. and i didn't understand how should i ave the file in UTF-8 charset encoding. sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I made your example UTF-8. Check whether you still see the problem. If not, revert the question using an edit. If you do see it, try removing the fontenc package, removing the theorem from the beginning of the document, then the theorem-related commands before the begindocument (i.e. remove each of these and re-compile both on Mac and on Windows).

Comment: compiling this file with mactex didn't solve the issue. and trying to compile this with miktex didn't work at all. the error is:
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8x'. and i couldn't install this package successfully.

Comment: Then just use your original file and try the removals I suggested. Note that the problem is not supposed to be resolved, I'm just trying to help you narrow it down.

Comment: I did use the removals. it didn't affect anything. now I don't see what can I do next.

Comment: If it didn't affect anything, that's _good_ - you can minimize your example. Edit your question appropriately.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you have any suggestion about what to do next?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure... but at least now you have a very clear question that people familiar with MacTeX should be able to solve... I suggest we both remove our long line of comments here, it's no longer useful. If you had more reputation you could put a bounty on it...

Comment: Maybe you could try the options [here](www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=letterspace) as a workaround (although I'm not sure that will work for Hebrew text).