# How to input lyx file into .tex file

Tags: lyx, input

I would like to input the body of a lyx file into a tex file.

Currently I convert the .lyx file (say child.lyx) to child.tex in Lyx with `File > Export > Latex`, and use `\input{child.tex}` in the main .tex document, also using the standalone package to only copy the body, which works.

Somehow, if I have my main document in `LyX` and use `\input{}` in Lyx (`Insert > File > Child Document ...`), it works as well, but directly using `\input{child.lyx}` in `LaTeX` doesn't work.

Is there a way to avoid the conversion step, so that I could simply write in child.lyx and compile main.tex file, without having to convert the lyx file first each time?

Comment: there is no way to insert a LyX document with `\input{}` inside LaTeX. Only the other way round is possible.

Comment: I see. But is there any way I could input the tex code in the code preview pane that I see in Lyx into a tex document besides copy-pasting it?

Comment: Please refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/converting-lyx-to-latex

Answer (score 1):

LyX is mainly a front-end to LaTeX format (and other formats, but this is another history) and it seems able to convert the main and child LyX files to a PDF directly, but in the background,  making the PDFs is the exclusive business of LaTeX.

LaTeX is not at all a front-end of LyX, it have no idea about any other format, so simply it cannot manage `\input{child.lyx}`.

In the screen you can see `Input: child.lyx`  but if you open un the menu the <kbd>Code Preview Pane</kbd>  you will see that the latex version will be `\input{child.tex}`.  LyX will take care of export the child files behind the scenes when needed, but for LaTeX, the LyX files are a parallel universe.

Note that in LaTeX he extension `.tex` is assumed when `\input` or `\include`  have an argument without extension tha is not found (e.g.: `\input{foo}` search first for file `foo.tex` and if this file does not exist, will search only `foo`). For some unknown reason, LyX omit the extension only for `\include`, so `Include: child.lyx` will be exported as  `\include{child}` instead of `\include{child.tex}` but in any case Latex will search for `child.tex`.

[image: mwe]